# Oracle ODI: Creating Tables with Dynamic Names using a Knowledge Module

Tags: oracle

I need to create auditing tables in Oracle using a Loading Knowledge Module (LKM).

Knowledge Modules typically create various tables, triggers and views which are named dynamically, e.g.: C$_tablename, J$_tablename, T$_tablename, JV$_tablename, etc. etc.

I would like to do something similar for my auditing tables, i.e. all audit tables would be called "tablename_audit", but do not how to set this up in the LKM code.

As an example, the following LKM code is used to create a C$ work table:

```
create table <%=odiRef.getTable("L", "COLL_NAME", "A")%>
(
    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "[CX_COL_NAME]\t[DEST_WRI_DT] NULL", ",\n\t", "","")%>
)
```

And the following IKM code creates an I$ flow table:

```
create table <%=odiRef.getTable("L", "INT_NAME", "W")%>
(
    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "[COL_NAME]\t[DEST_WRI_DT] NULL", ",\n\t", "", "")%>
    ,IND_UPDATE     char(1)
)
```

INT_NAME and COLL_NAME seem to be constants defined in the Substitution API, as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/integrate.1111/e12645/odiref_reference.htm).

So, how can I use the knowledge module to create similar tables with dynamic names in an Oracle Database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this as follows.

`<%=odiRef.getTable("L", "TARG_NAME", "A")%>` returns the target table name in DATABASE."tablename" format.

I therefore added a step to my LKM which uses Jython to extract the tablename from the DATABASE."tablename" string, append "_audit" to the table name, and then save the DATABASE."tablename_audit" string to a Jython variable, as shown below.

```
targTableName = '<%=odiRef.getTable("L", "TARG_NAME", "A")%>'
splitStr = targTableName.split('"')
JYTHON_AUDIT_TABLE = splitStr[0] + '\"' + splitStr[1] + '_audit\"'
```

However, since Jython variables cannot be used from SQL scripts in ODI, I added another step to my LKM which fetches the Jython variable into a Java variable (which can then be used by ODI objects) using [ODI Expert's Jython to Java API](http://odiexperts.com/odi-parallel-2/#jythontojava).

```
import api.getInfo as info;

info.setJythonVariable(JYTHON_AUDIT_TABLE);

<@
import api.getInfo;
String JAVA_AUDIT_TABLE = getInfo.getJythonVariable();
@>
```

I could then easily use the `JAVA_AUDIT_TABLE` variable in my SQL scripts to create the required tables in my target database.

```
create table <@=JAVA_AUDIT_TABLE@>...

insert into <@=JAVA_AUDIT_TABLE@>...
```

Comment: any idea about how to adapt your code in such a way to obtain the column type? I need that information to use it in the condition of an if-else statement :D

Comment: Sorry, was working on this over 5 years ago and no longer remember or have access to the code. :( Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation but with columns. I followed your steps and I am running into error when setting up the java variable. I might not be using the correct technology or doing something stupid.

I used Java bean shell technology in command on source and used the code snippet you provided.

It would be really helpful if you could you please provide more information like technology you used in command on source and target.